# Access Denied when trying to change directories in command prompt

Tags: command-line, permissions, ruby

I'm trying to learn Ruby, and I'm pretty new to anything related to the command line, but so far everything seems to be working okay other than when I change directories. I can write ruby scripts, and in order to run them I have to save them directly in c:/users/elliot as I can't change directories, even to newly created folders. I know after a while, it will become a mess of files and hard to find anything if I keep saving everything in the same folder....does anyone know how to fix this? My user account is the admin + the only account even on this computer. I checked the permissions of my C:/, C:/users, and C:/users/elliot and all of them say I have full permissions. My UAC slider is also all the way at the bottom. Anyone know how to get past this? Thanks!

Comment: "I can't change directories, even to newly created folders."  why not?  What do you type, and what response do you get?  Are things any different if right-click on icon for command prompt, and choose "Run as Administrator"?  What version of Windows?  I presume you mean C:\Users\elliot (backslash, not forward slash)

Comment: I've tried run as admin, it gives the same error. 'Access is denied' -- sorry, I dunno why I did forward slashes here, I've been using backslashes in the command prompt. I made a new directory called 'Ruby' and I've been trying to use the command cd > Ruby, also have tried cd> C:\Users\Elliot\Ruby, have also tried to navigate to pretty much any other directory in Users\Elliot and every time Access is denied.

Comment: Still no answer on what version of Windows.  If you mkdir C:\Temp do you get better results there?  How about under %TEMP% or %TMP% or %APPDATA% or %LOCALAPPDATA% or %HOMEPATH% or %ALLUSERSPROFILE% ?  Have you tried both a traditional command prompt (CMD) and PowerShell?

Comment: I have found the problem......every tutorial I have watched has instructed me to use the 'cd >' command....I never though until now of just trying cd without the > and it works now. Thanks anyways!

PS- mkdir didn't do anything at all. It just skipped a line and output C:\Users\Elliot as if it was ready for another command. I double checked windows explorer and it didn't create any new directory in C:\Users\Elliot. Should I concern myself with this? When i tried mkdir %TEMP% it gave me an error C:\Users\Elliot\AppData\Local\Temp already exists

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem was not caused by permissions, but a lack of clarity of how the commands work.

You should see a prompt that shows your folders.  If not, typing:

> PROMPT $P$G

may help.

I suggest running:

> cd %USERPROFILE
> mkdir demo
> cd demo
> start .
> mkdir subdir
> cd subdir
> cd

The "start ." will cause Windows Explorer to open up, showing you the contents of your directory.  Notice that when you type "mkdir subdir", then the graphical Windows Explorer will show you the directory that you just created.

I think that will help to solidify what these commands are doing.

The > has a special meaning (called "redirection", although two of them in a row are called "append").  That may be worth learning someday, but is a more advanced topic/concept than being able to determine the effects of some of these commands.  Until that is comfortably understood, I suggest just staying away from typing the > character at the command prompt.